# Module not found: Error: Package path ./lib/react-markdown is not exported from package E:\studynotion6\studynotion6\node_modules\react-markdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-markdown

```
Module not found: Error: Package path ./lib/react-markdown is not exported from package E:\studynotion6\studynotion6\node_modules\react-markdown (see exports field in E:\studynotion6\studynotion6\node_modules\react-markdown\package.json)
```

Getting this error how to solve?

Tried to `install react-markdown`.

Comment: Can you update your post with the code where you try to import from `./lib/react-markdown`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.